# Get XML attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

This is my XML:

```
<response errors="0"><person><middlename/><name>Egor</name><carsList><car default="true">0777AD</car></carsList><surname>Petrov</surname></person><funds>505.56</funds></response>
```

I need to get the value of the `default` attribute for the `<car>` element.

I found some solutions on Stack Overflow with `attr()` and `attributue()` but I had no success using them.

My code is:

```
unless @account.xpath("//person//carslist").blank?
  @account.xpath("//person//carslist").each do |car|

    p car.attribute('default')

  end
end
```

On my console I see nil but need to see true.

The correctly variant is:

```
unless @account.xpath("//person//carsList/*").blank?
  @account.xpath("//person//carsList/*").each do |car|

    p car.attribute('default').content

  end
end
```

What can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
unless @account.xpath("//person//carsList/*").blank?
```

Notice the capital 'L' in `carsList` instead of `carslist`. Also note the `/*` to get the child nodes of `carList`.

The corrected code would be:

```
  unless @account.xpath("//person//carsList/*").blank?
    @account.xpath("//person//carsList").each do |car|

      p car.attribute('default')

    end
  end
```

Comment: i have always nil, but not true

Comment: I tried it and it worked for me if you use `//person//carsList` as your xpath instead of `//person//carslist`

Comment: for me it doesn't work.
Also in my `@account` i have response from
`@account = Nokogiri::XML(open('httyp://...'))`

Comment: oops sorry I see what you're getting at. The car.attribute('default') bit is returning nil. Updated code above with correction

Comment: i've updated my post with correctly code. Thank u, your code was helpful for me